# Merge property with value on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In project I have one table:

```
item_attributes(
    id,
    property varchar, // year for example
    type varchar,
    value varchar, // 1999 for example
)
```

In Laravel I want to merge property and value so when I select item response should be

```
year => 1999
```

When I'm selecting item with attributes response is this:
[image]

```
Item::with("attributes")->get()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you show us some code?

Comment: If you are using Laravel Eloquent Model then this would definitely help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Comment: @Mozammil I updated my question

Comment: Thanks. I added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to return a custom `json data` when returning one or more models of the same type, you can use `Resources` which are just another layer in charge of transforming the data you want to return from your application, since the question is not specific, I will give you a link where you can check out more about this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#generating-resources

Answer (score 0):

In Your Model you should create one attribute like this. and then whenever you want that property value response then use this attribute.

```
public function getPropertyValueAttribute()
{
   return "{$this->property} => {$this->value}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `pluck()` should work.

```
Item::with("attributes")
    ->get()
    ->pluck('attributes.value', 'attributes.property');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Item Model Class define a method like:

```
// Assumed that an item "hasMany" attributes:
function getItemAttributesAttribute() {
    $attr = [];
    foreach($this->attributes as $attribute) {
      $attr[$attribute->property] = $attribute->value;
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

And use it in your controller as:

```
dd(Item::get()->first()->item_attributes);
// or
dd(Item::find(1)->item_attributes);
```

If you want to get multiple items with attributes:

```
$list = [];
foreach(Item::get() as $item) {
    $list[$item->id] = $item->item_attributes; 
}
dd($list);
```